# Display: grid breaks inner element's width

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I have a dropdown list and two buttons inside a material card.
When I click on the dropdown **quickly after reloading the page** (say within the first 2 seconds), the width of the buttons sometimes collapse. The effect does not occur when I stay on the page a while (say 10 seconds) and then click on the dropdown.

I noticed that the effect does not occur when I remove the outer `display: grid`. Why does this effect occur? What can I do to get rid of it? I need the grid for other stuff I intentionally left out in the [Stackblitz (Full)](https://angular-ivy-lno1c8.stackblitz.io)

[Stackblitz (Edit)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lno1c8)

Error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issues is with the `align-items: baseline;`
If it's not completly required, you may change it to `center` or `start`.

Also, I suggest you the [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/repeat()) function for grid column:

```css
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    column-gap: 24px;
    align-items: center; // baseline -> center

    &.second {
        row-gap: 24px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    }
}
```

or just override it for `.second`, in case this causes any issue with other elements:

```css
&.second {
    align-items: center;
    row-gap: 24px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Replacing the line `align-items: baseline;` with `align-items: center;` fixed the issue.
Also thanks for pointing out the `repeat()` function. It is truly helpful.